# Units of `ru_maxrss` on BSD?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, bsd, getrusage

`getrusage` returns a struct containing

```
long ru_maxrss;       /* max resident set size */
```

What are the units of `ru_maxrss`, on BSD operating systems?  Is this value in bytes, or in kilobytes?  By "BSD", I mean FreeBSD, OpenBSD, but not Mac OS X / Darwin.

The [FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.3-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) and [OpenBSD man page](http://man.openbsd.org/getrusage.2) say the units are in kilobytes:

```
 ru_maxrss    the maximum resident set size utilized (in kilobytes).
```

However, I know that on Darwin / Mac OS X, the units are in bytes (even though online man pages claim otherwise), and I have also found some statements online that claim on BSD `ru_maxrss` is also returned in bytes (see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30940/getrusage-system-call-what-is-maximum-resident-set-size#comment552809_30940)).  Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On FreeBSD it's in kilobytes, as evidenced by the source in kern_clock.c:

```
/* Update resource usage integrals and maximums. */
MPASS(p->p_vmspace != NULL);
vm = p->p_vmspace;
ru = &td->td_ru;
ru->ru_ixrss += pgtok(vm->vm_tsize) * cnt;
ru->ru_idrss += pgtok(vm->vm_dsize) * cnt;
ru->ru_isrss += pgtok(vm->vm_ssize) * cnt;
rss = pgtok(vmspace_resident_count(vm));
if (ru->ru_maxrss < rss)
    ru->ru_maxrss = rss;
```

`pgtok()` computes kb from page size.

But who would believe the kernel source? Lets run a program:

```
$ cat x.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct rusage r;

    if (getrusage( RUSAGE_SELF, &r) == 0) {
       printf ("ru_maxrss=%lu\n", (unsigned long)r.ru_maxrss);
    }
    return 0;
}
$ ./a.out
ru_maxrss=5824
$ ./a.out
ru_maxrss=0
$ ./a.out
ru_maxrss=216
$ ./a.out
ru_maxrss=1880
```

These numbers aren't multiples of 1024, so can't be bytes.